# extjs grid with calculations for the grouping summary

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am having a grid with 4 columns, ( site, nombre, vitesse, and temps cime)

I want to get a row for each of the grouping with the summaries:
1. a number of row for the column 'site'
2. the sum for the 'nombre' column
3. the average value of for the column 'vitesse'
4. the average value of the column temps cime

This is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/P2e7s/14/

I tried the

```
summaryType: 'count',
summaryRenderer: function(value) { };
```

but the doesn' t make any difference, don' t know where the problem is coming from.

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

No really sure what you mean for column 'site'. You need to add the feature 'SummaryRow' to get any of them to work. Got the other summaries working (cant save to fiddle atm so long post incoming):

```
Ext.application({
name: 'SC',
appFolder: 'app',
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],

launch: function() {


    // #region Documents traités grid
    // Documents traités grid
    // model documents traités
    Ext.define('SC.model.DocTraites', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: "organisme"
        }, {
            name: "site",
        }, {
            name: "wat_nbr",
            type: "int"
        }, {
            name: "wat_vit",
            type: "float"
        }, {
            name: "ged_nbr",
            type: "int"
        }, {
            name: "ged_vit",
            dateFormat: "float"
        }, {
            name: "sic_nbr",
            type: "int"
        }, {
            name: "sic_vit",
            type: "float",
        }, {
            name: "tem_cim",
            type: "float",
        }]
    });


    // store documents traités
    Ext.define('SC.store.DocTraites', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
        model: "SC.model.DocTraites",
        data: [
            ["Centre Fend 1", "Site 1", 8545, 25, 521, 125, 2545, 12, 59.47],
            ["Centre Fend 1", "Site 2", 868, 25, 521, 125, 557, 12, 39.57],
            ["Centre Fend 2", "Site 3", 3633, 25, 521, 125, 544, 12, 29.47],
            ["Centre Fend 4", "Site 4", 545, 25, 521, 125, 5445, 12, 49.4],
            ["Centre Fend 5", "Site 5", 6445, 25, 521, 125, 7514, 12, 69.7],
            ["Centre Fend 1", "Site 6", 3633, 25, 521, 125, 544, 12, 29.47],
            ["Centre Fend 2", "Site 7", 545, 25, 521, 125, 5445, 12, 49.4],
            ["Centre Fend 5", "Site 8", 6445, 25, 521, 125, 7514, 12, 69.7],

            ],
        groupField: 'organisme'
    });

    Ext.create('SC.store.DocTraites', {
        storeId: 'DocTraites'
    });

    // view doxuments traites
    Ext.define('SC.view.grid.GroupedHeaderGrid', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        xtype: 'documents-traites',
        store: 'DocTraites',
        columnLines: true,
        height: 350,
        title: 'Documents traités',
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        },
        features: [{
            ftype: 'grouping',
            startCollapsed: true
        }, {
            ftype: 'summary'
        }],
        initComponent: function() {
            this.width = 800;
            this.columns = [{
                text: 'Site',
                width: 200,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'site',
                summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                    // DO STUFF
                },

            }, {
                text: 'App',
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Nombre',
                    width: 75,
                    sortable: true,
                    dataIndex: 'wat_nbr',
                    summaryType: 'sum'
                }, {
                    text: 'Vitesse',
                    sortable: true,
                    renderer: function(val) {
                        if (val > 10) {
                            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
                        } else if (val < 0) {
                            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
                        }
                        return val;
                    },
                    dataIndex: 'wat_vit',
                    summaryType: 'average'
                }]
            }, {
                text: 'Temps Cime',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'tem_cim',
                summaryType: 'average'
            }];

            this.callParent();
        }
    });

    // This is to put into the launch function ( don' t forget to put above launch: name : 'SC',

    Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'documents-traites',
        renderTo: document.body
    });

    // End Documents traités grid

    // #region Detail corbeille
    // model detail corbeille        
    Ext.define('DetailCorbeille', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['name', 'watt', 'ged', 'sicomor']
    });

    // Store that contains several User instances.
    var detailCorbeille = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'TempsCime',
        data: [{
            name: 'Libellé local 1',
            watt: '10',
            ged: '886',
            sicomor: '78'
        }, {
            name: 'Libellé local 2',
            watt: '542',
            ged: '676',
            sicomor: '76'
        }, {
            name: 'Libellé local 3',
            watt: '544',
            ged: '96',
            sicomor: '67'
        }, {
            name: 'Libellé local 4',
            watt: '88',
            ged: '969',
            sicomor: '786'
        }, {
            name: 'Libellé local 5',
            watt: '55',
            ged: '676',
            sicomor: '6'
        }, ]
    });

    // display the data using a Grid Panel
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: detailCorbeille,
        width: 800,
        height: 250,
        columnLines: true,
        title: 'Detail par corbeille',
        columns: [{
            text: '',
            //width: 100,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 2,
        }, {
            text: 'Stock initial',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'watt',
            hidden: false,
        }, {
            text: 'Ancienneté',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'ged',
        }, {
            text: 'Entrées',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'sicomor',
        }, {
            text: 'Sorties',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'sicomor',
        }, {
            text: 'Stock final',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'sicomor',
        }, {
            text: 'Indexeurs',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'sicomor',
        }, {
            text: 'Cadence moyenne',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'sicomor',
        }, {
            text: 'Temps restant',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'sicomor',
        }, ]
    });

    // #endregion End Cime Temps chart 



}
```

});

Basically, just added the feature to the grid and switched some of the summaytypes.

Hope this helps

Comment: If you need to get a Count of records, try:
summaryRenderer: function(value) {
return this.store.getCount();
},